# Extended links in citations

Tags: latex, bibliography, citations, biblatex

I am using the below code for citations.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable,adjustbox,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}

\addbibresource{segmentation.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a sample \cite{sample}.

\end{document}
```

The output that I am getting is:

[image]

However, I want the entire Author, Year to get linked, that is, the entire Author Year is blue and when I click on it, it takes me to the relevant page in the bibliography.

Could you please help me with that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the `\cite` macro like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array,booktabs,dcolumn,threeparttable,adjustbox,dirtytalk,multirow,tabularx,booktabs,longtable,placeins,tikz}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\psset{unit=2cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a sample \citep{knuth:ct}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) However, this works with \citep{}, not \citet{}. How do we modify the macro to do this for \citet?